# Xamarin Forms Button TextColor behaves differently on Android than an iOS

Tags: button, xamarin.forms, textcolor

I want a button's text color to be the same on both iOS and Android. So I thought I'd just set the TextColor property in code to the color I wanted. On iOS, the disabled text color is still grey (which is what I want), however, on Android, the disabled text color is the same as the enabled text color. How do I make the disabled text color on Android grey (or whatever its default is for a disabled button)?
Thanks

Comment: Use custom renderers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49193488/1039935

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That is the default behavior in Xamarin.Forms. To work around that and achieve a custom color, you can:

- use triggers to change the color when going from enabled to disabled and vice versa
- manually set the color when enabling and disabling the button
- use a custom renderer

Because triggers are the most straightforward and consistent way of achieving what you want, I'll only cover that. You can see the xamarin [docs](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/custom-renderer/) for more information about custom renderers.

Using triggers, you can dynamically change the font color to gray when it is not enabled. See the [docs](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/working-with/triggers/) for more information about triggers.

```
<Button Text="I am a Button">
<Button.Triggers>
    <Trigger TargetType="Button"
         Property="IsEnabled" Value="true">
        <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Red" />
        <!-- red is the desired color when the button is enabled.-->
    </Trigger>
    <Trigger TargetType="Button"
         Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
        <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Gray" />
        <!-- gray is the desired color when the button is disabled.-->
    </Trigger>
</Button.Triggers>
</Button>
```

Answer (score 1):

If above does not work for you, you could try to check [this workaround](http://byteloom.marek-mierzwa.com/mobile/2017/06/08/disabled-button-style-on-ios-in-xamarin-forms.html). It uses a custom renderer and `NSAttributedString` for setting the title in disabled state