# How can I change the text color of a disabled button?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Currently, I have something like this inside my view:

```
public void DisableNextBtn(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(emailentry.Text))
    {
        NextButton.IsEnabled = false;
        NextButton.TextColor = Color.FromRgba(0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x80);
    }
    else
    {
        NextButton.IsEnabled = true;
        NextButton.TextColor = Color.White;
    }
}
```

However, even though I want to set the TextColor of the button to the color above, it won't change from the default dark disabled state text color. How can I change the TextColor for my button?

I have a custom button already, so I was thinking maybe there is a way to change the textcolor of disabled state button inside my custom renderer but I'm not entirely sure.

This is for Xamarin.Forms Android app.

Comment: use `NextButton.SetTextColor(Color.FromRgba(0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x80));` **instead of** `NextButton.TextColor = Color.FromRgba(0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x80);`

Comment: @IshitaSinha this is for Xamarin.Forms

Comment: maybe this post will help? http://stackoverflow.com/a/32425851/5746918

Comment: use drawable to change color for disabled/touched/focused

Answer (score 2):

```
            btn.SetTextColor(Color.Rgb(0:255, 0:255, 0:255));
```

Comment: Please explain your answer

Comment: NextButton.SetTextColor(Color.Rgb(0,255,0)); this will make the text to green

Answer (score 0):

```
mBtnEmail.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.text_gray));
```

Comment: This is for Xamarin.Forms Android app

Answer (score 0):

In xamarin forms android, I just did this in my `styles.xml` for my disabled `textcolor`. I'm sure it's the same for button `textcolor`.

```
<item name="android:textColor">@android:color/black</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change it using `NextButton.ForeColor = Color.FromRgba(0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x80);`.

Answer (score 0):

if you'd like to change the color so it becomes like the color of it background, wich means you want to hide the text, you can do:

```
button1.Text = "";
button1.Enabled = true;
```